# Email to SMS using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Good Day, I found in google that you can send sms messages just by typing the recipients mobile number plus the sms gateway using phpmailer and I tested it on my mobile phone but for some reason I don't received any sms messages. This is my php code:

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
// Configure smptp
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';
// Authentication
$mail->Username = "**********@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "******";
// Compose
$mail->Subject = "Testing";
$mail->Body = "Testing";
// Send to
$mail->AddAddress("***********@mysmart.mymobile.ph");
var_dump($mail->send()); //Send!
```

and here is the var_dump
[image]

I am residing in the philippines. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you familiar with Exception-Handling and error-reporting?

Comment: Sorry but I don't...

Comment: Then star with adding two lines on the top of your php file..error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: I added the two lines please check if something new to the lines above..

Comment: then run your php file..It will display the errors..

Comment: I already run it and displays the new added picture above.... but still I don't received any sms from it.

Comment: we really dont need that the array output from the var_dump() function..

Comment: That's good..There is no errors in your code..

Comment: I already directed sending email from gmail but still I don't received any sms. Is it the gateway is not working.

Comment: But we need an exception-handler..

Comment: side note: operator email to sms gateways are notoriously unreliable, if you actually want to send sms via email\web sign up for a 'real' sms-gateway

Comment: I don't know if they support all countries...

Comment: the above will only work for phone numbers registered to mysmart.mymobile.ph to cover all mobile carrieres you need a dedicated sms-gaeway

Comment: Yes , I am one of their subscribers that's why I am confused why I can't get any sms from the code that I created.

Comment: tested normal maill?

Comment: I test it to send via web gmail  but it seems the gateway does not respond.

Comment: Right now I am searching free sms api to test if its in the gateway provider or the code really does not work.

Comment: Is there free sms api that I can use because the ones that I searched have all hidden charges like telling its free but you just need to buy sms credits to start sending sms.